# Reassigning correct ID to subdivs

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have dynamic form that is created in jquery and so you can add Champions which are like main categories.

Then you can add General Changes which are like subcategories.

And if you have 3 champions  with IDs like 1 2 3 with and each one of them has it's own subcategories and then you delete the middle one (ID - 2) ID's will change to 1 and 3 will jump into the place of second one and change the ID to 2 so it will be in numerical order.

Subcategories have also IDs [1,2,3,4] which are the numbers of champions so when I delete 2 champion categories should also change accordingly.

Here is a picture showing my problem, now where you can see green [2][0] and [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eT6J2.png) it is [3][0] and [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eT6J2.png)

[image: image problem]

Here is HTML

```
    <div id="wrap">
    <form name="second_form" id="second_form" action="#" method="POST"> <a href="#" id="AddChampion" onclick="return false;">Add Champion</a>

        <div id="ChampionInput"></div>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit">
    </form>
</div>
```

JQUERY:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#second_form').removeAttr('novalidate');
    championNumberArray = 0;
    championNumber = 1;
    $('a#AddChampion').on('click', function () {
        $('div#ChampionInput').append(
            '<div class="Champion" data-id="' + championNumberArray + '">\
             <a href="#" class="Remove" onclick="return false;">Remove</a>\
             <br>\
             <input type="text" class="ChampionInput" list="champions" name="champion[]" placeholder="Champion ' + championNumber + '" required>\
             <a href="#" class="AddGeneralChange" onclick="return false;">Add General Change</a>\
             <div class="GeneralChanges">\
             </div>\
             <br>\
         <div>');
        championNumberArray++;
        championNumber++;
    });
    $('div#ChampionInput').on('click', 'a.Remove', function () {
        var champion = $(this).closest('.Champion');
        var id = champion.data("id");
        var nextChampion = champion;
        while ((nextChampion = nextChampion.next()).length != 0) {
            nextChampion.attr("data-id", id++);
            nextChampion.children('.ChampionInput').attr('placeholder', 'Champion ' + id);
        }
        championNumber = id + 1;
        championNumberArray = id;
        champion.remove();
    });
    $('div#ChampionInput').on('click', 'a.AddGeneralChange', function () {
        $(this).siblings('.GeneralChanges').append(
            '<div class="GeneralChange">\
                <textarea type="text" size="20" rows="3" cols="50" maxlength="500" name="GeneralChangeDescription[' + $(this).parent('div').data('id') + '][]" placeholder="Enter General Change Description" required></textarea>\
                <a href="#" class="RemoveGeneralChange" onclick="return false;">Remove General Change</a>\
            </div>');
    });
    $('div#ChampionInput').on('click', 'a.RemoveGeneralChange', function () {
        $(this).closest('.GeneralChange').remove();
    });

});
```

Here is also a working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4b2ogxwz/

Comment: That's the common issue with using `id` attribute with dynamic HTML.

Comment: @MaxZoom that's the first time I'm dealing with dynamic HTML and JQuery tbh so I might be doing something completely wrong is there an easier way to achieve what I want to?

Comment: why are the ID's important for you? if it's just for the time where you submit then on the submit function you can add them.

Comment: @Saar how will I get the correct order after submiting the form without those ID's

Comment: add javascript function "createIds" which assign ids by order:  `<input type="submit" name="submit" onsubmit="createIds()">`

Comment: @Saar but how will it know to which Champion ->category which subcategory is assigned to

Comment: Instead of `id` use `data` attributes described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes)

Comment: something like this (you will probably need to change it to fit your logic but you should get it): `function changeIds(){
 var champions = $(".Champion");
 for(var i = 0; i < champions.length; i++){
  var generalChanges = champions[i].find(".GeneralChange");
  for(var j = 0; j < generalChanges.length; j++){
   generalChanges[j].attr("name","GeneralChangeDescription["+i+"]["+j+"]");
  }
 }
}`